# Multi-class semi-supervised classification code (SVM, co-training, Graph-based)?

Tags: classification, svm, semi-supervised-learning

I am trying to evaluate the performance of my semi-supervised algorithm, by comparing it against different algorithms. I have searched a lot, but can't find code that does multi-class semi-supervised classification by training on (labeled + Unlabeled ) data and then testing on unseen data. Most that I have come across are designed for 2-class problems. Can anyone point me where I can find code for multi-class problems?